# Wait until all requests are completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm implementing website and have 2 problems. I'm using jQuery 3.

1) I'm sending 2 AJAX requests and need in case of failure I would like to get information from both requests. I'm using code like this:

```
let ajaxCalls = [];

if (logoUploaded) {
    const sendPhoto = $.ajax({
        type: submit.data('ajax-logo-create-method').toUpperCase(),
        url: submit.data('ajax-logo-create-url'),
        headers: headers,
        data: {file: logo},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // here another request would be run
            sleep(500).then(() => {
                console.log('was sleeping 500 ms');
            });
            sleep(10000).then(() => {
                console.log('was sleeping 10000 ms');
            });
        }
    });
    ajaxCalls.push(sendPhoto);
}

const sendContactData = $.ajax({
    type: submit.data('ajax-data-method').toUpperCase(),
    url: submit.data('ajax-data-url'),
    headers: headers,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json'
});

ajaxCalls.push(sendContactData);

$.when.apply(this, ajaxCalls).then(function () {
    hideValidationErrors();
    showSendStatusMessage('#' + submit.data('ajax-update-ok'));
    submit.removeClass('ajax-js-working');

}, function() {
    let validationErrors = [];
    $.each(ajaxCalls, function (index, ajaxCall) {
        if (ajaxCall.status === 422) {
            json = $.parseJSON(ajaxCall.responseText);
            console.log(json);
            $.each(json.errors, function (field, messages) {
                validationErrors.push({'field': field, 'messages': messages});
            });
        }
    });

    hideValidationErrors();

    if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
        $.each(validationErrors, function (id, object) {
            wrapper = $('#' + object.field + '-container');
            wrapper.addClass('error');
            displayValidationErrorMessages(wrapper, object.messages);
        });
    }

    showSendStatusMessage('#' + submit.data('ajax-update-error'));
    submit.removeClass('ajax-js-working');
});
```

But unfortunately when using this code it seems that `$when .. then` is waiting only for 1st failed request and I need to have both of them here.

2) Second problem is what I have in success in 1st request. In some cases when this request is done and was successful I will have to run another request and I would like to in such case run `$.when.apply(this, ajaxCalls).then(function () {` when request from success was completed. Is it possible to achieve this?

If possible, please give me full code sample what changes I should do to make it working.

Comment: Try `Promise.all(ajaxCalls).then`

Comment: Have you tried nesting the second `$.ajax` function in the success callback of the first? Also, you may want to reconsider using user submitted data for setting properties, especially for the `url`.

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode Not really, those 2 should execute in same time, I just want to process result of them together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did, was adding both started and finished requests to arrays (`ajaxCalls` and `doneAjaxCalls`) like this:

```
let ajaxCalls = [];
let doneAjaxCalls = [];

const fileInput = $('img#uploadedImg');

const fileExisted = fileInput.hasClass('imgExisted');
const fileWasRemoved = fileInput.hasClass('imgDeleted');
const fileWasUploaded = fileInput.hasClass('newImgUploaded');

const logo = fileInput.attr('src');

const needRemovePhoto = fileExisted && (fileWasRemoved || fileWasUploaded);

if (needRemovePhoto) {
    const removePhoto = $.ajax({
        type: submit.data('ajax-logo-delete-method').toUpperCase(),
        url: submit.data('ajax-logo-delete-url'),
        headers: headers,
        data: {file: logo},
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (response) {
            doneAjaxCalls.push(response);
            handleMultipleAjaxCalls(submit, ajaxCalls, doneAjaxCalls);
        },
        success: function (response) {
            fileInput.removeClass('imgDeleted');
            fileInput.removeClass('imgExisted');
            if (fileWasUploaded) {
                const sendPhoto = $.ajax({
                    type: submit.data('ajax-logo-create-method').toUpperCase(),
                    url: submit.data('ajax-logo-create-url'),
                    headers: headers,
                    data: {file: logo},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        fileInput.addClass('imgExisted');
                    },
                    complete: function (response) {
                        doneAjaxCalls.push(response);
                        handleMultipleAjaxCalls(submit, ajaxCalls, doneAjaxCalls);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                doneAjaxCalls.push(response);
                handleMultipleAjaxCalls(submit, ajaxCalls, doneAjaxCalls);
            }
        }
    });
    ajaxCalls.push(removePhoto);
}
else if (fileWasUploaded) {
    const sendPhoto = $.ajax({
        type: submit.data('ajax-logo-create-method').toUpperCase(),
        url: submit.data('ajax-logo-create-url'),
        headers: headers,
        data: {file: logo},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            fileInput.addClass('imgExisted');
        },
        complete: function (response) {
            doneAjaxCalls.push(response);
            handleMultipleAjaxCalls(submit, ajaxCalls, doneAjaxCalls);
        }
    });
    ajaxCalls.push(sendPhoto);
}

const sendContactData = $.ajax({
    type: submit.data('ajax-method').toUpperCase(),
    url: submit.data('ajax-url'),
    headers: headers,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function (response) {
        doneAjaxCalls.push(response);
        handleMultipleAjaxCalls(submit, ajaxCalls, doneAjaxCalls);
    }
});

ajaxCalls.push(sendContactData);
```

As you see in multiple cases I call then `handleMultipleAjaxCalls` function and I defined this function like this:

```
window.handleMultipleAjaxCalls = function (submit, ajaxCalls, doneAjaxCalls) {
    // if not all expected requests were done (success or failure), do nothing
    if (doneAjaxCalls.length < ajaxCalls.length) {
        return;
    }

    // here we know that all expected AJAX requests were completed (success or failure)

    // here more logic after all requests are completed
});
```

so in I execute this function in more cases it could happen the logic should be launched and inside this function I compare if all started ajaxcalls are really finished (just simple length of array comparison)